# Round time in Teradata to 5 minute

Tags: time, rounding, teradata

I have COL_1 as timestamp which looks like this 5:04:00. I want to round it down to something that looks like this 05:00:00.

So basically round down to a 5 minute bucket. And, add leading zero to hours if needed.

Meaning, 5:01:00 changes to 05:00:00

14:59:00-->14:55:00

14:51:00-->14:50:00

7:13:00-->07:10:00

Comment: Is this actually a timestamp? A timestamp includes a date part. Are there no seconds, only minutes?

Comment: My bad! Its a VARCHAR(5)

Comment: There are no seconds. The column actually looks like 05:00 for 5AM in Teradata SQL Assistant. - @dnoeth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you store this in a VarChar instead of Time or Interval?

```
CAST(col AS TIME(0) FORMAT 'hh:mi')     - 
( (EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM 
  CAST(col AS TIME(0) FORMAT 'hh:mi')
           ) MOD 5
  ) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CAST(TO_CHAR(INPUT_TS,'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' ' || 
CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM INPUT_TS) > 30 THEN 
     TRIM(TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM INPUT_TS) + 1,'00')) 
ELSE TRIM(TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM INPUT_TS)    ,'00')) 
    END || ':00:00' AS TIMESTAMP(6)) AS YOUR_TS
```

Format as required.